# Trim on a table column in SQL Server 2005

Tags: string, sql-server-2005, trim

I have a table called `Examination` and a column `Name`. In this `Name` column lot of values are with leading spaces and trailing spaces. I want to know how to update this column so that there are no spaces in the values.

Comment: And also i have a doubt in csharp code. I want to apply trim to this reader["Manager"].ToString().ToUpper()==Email; How to apply trim for reader["Manager"] this value.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to fix the existing data:

```
UPDATE Examination SET Name = RTRIM(LTRIM(Name))
```

Generally in your application layer you should "clean" the data before it goes into the database.

The [RTRIM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx) function will remove trailing space on the right, and [LTRIM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177827.aspx) will remove it on the left.

In C#, you can trim both the left and the right using the [Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) method on string, which will return a new string trimmed.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE Examination SET [Name] = LTRIM(RTRIM([Name]))
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: The only reason I didn't is because a) it's the only text in the answer and b) it isn't wide enough to wrap.

Comment: OK - **but** formatting it brings out syntax highlighting which is both nice and also useful

Answer (score 1):

Get the Maximum value for e.g. any S.No or ID from your Examination table.Let us consider ID as u r serial number.

```
declare @TotCount int

select @Totcount=MAX(id) from @t
WHILE(@Totcount > 0)
BEGIN

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM EXAMINATION WHERE ID=@Totcount )
BEGIN
  UPDATE Examination
  Set Name=Rtrim(LTRIM(NAME))
  WHERE id=@Totcount
END
SET @Totcount = @Totcount - 1

END

SELECT * FROM Examination (NOLOCK)
```